# Standard Helvetica font

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I'm loading a .psd that's missing Helvetica and I'm trying to determine if any one of these fonts matches the original one used (I just installed a Helvetica font family pack).

My choices in Photoshop now are:

Helvetica Inserat LT Std
Helvetica LT STD
Helvetica Neue LT Com
Helvetica Rounded LT Std
Helvetica World

I'm just looking for standard Helvetica. Are any of these them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Helvetica LT Std* is a standard (Std) - regarding features and language coverage - Helvetica by Linotype (LT).

*Helvetica World* has the extensive language support (incl. Greek, Cyrillic, Arabic, Hebrew, Vientamese etc). The Western part of this is identical to the previous one.

*Helvetica Rounded* is obviously a rounded version of Helvetica.

*Helvetica Inserat* is specifically a bold compressed style of Helvetica.

*Helvetica Neue* is a more modern reworking of Helvetica with many glyphs sufficiently altered.

So, answering your question, I think that you are looking for either of two first font families.